# Using cast in case when expression

Tags: sql, postgresql, casting, case, dbeaver

I want to write this type query :

```
SELECT 
  CASE 
      WHEN t1.date_closed - t1.created_date < t3.estimated_solution_time_minutes  THEN 'не в SL'
  ELSE 'в SL'
  END AS  result
```

but t1.date_closed and t1.created_date are intervals like this '2023-05-02 11:30',
but t3.estimated_solution_time_minutes is integer and i get error:   ERROR: operator does not exist: interval < integer

how can i cast these intervals to integer

Comment: Use:  `t1.date_closed - t1.created_date < make_interval(mins => t3.estimated_solution_time_minutes)`

Comment: I think this question needs an edit. Is `date_closed` really an `interval`? The name suggests otherwise, and `'2023-05-02 11:30'` is not an `interval`, but a `timestamp`.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is not the CAST.  In this case, you probably want `EXTRACT(SECONDS FROM (date_closed - created_date))`

Answer (score 0):

Yu can use this syntax for changing types

```
t1.date_closed :: INT
t1.created_date :: INT
```

the second way is

```
CAST(t1.date_closed as INT)
CAST(t1.created_date as INT)
```

Comment: where i write this syntax after select?

Comment: @Mike Organek thank you! your comment  solved problem